# добавление нескольких блоков с табами на страницу

Tags: javascript, tabs

Есть код

```js
const tabTabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tabs .tab');
const tabItems = document.querySelectorAll('.tabs-items .item');

for(let i = 0;i < tabTabs.length;i++) {
 tabTabs[0].click();
 tabTabs[i].onclick = () => {
   tabTabs.forEach((e)  => { e.classList.remove('on') }); 
  tabItems.forEach((e)  => { e.classList.remove('on') });
    tabTabs[i].classList.add('on');
    tabItems[i].classList.add('on');
  }
}
```

```css
.tabs .tab{display:inline-block;padding:5px 10px;margin:0 10px 20px 10px;border:1px solid #333;cursor:pointer}

.tabs .tab.on{background-color:coral}
.tabs-items .item{display:none}
.tabs-items .item.on{display:block}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <span class="tab">1</span>
  <span class="tab">2</span>
  <span class="tab">3</span>
</div>
<div class="tabs-items">
  <div class="item">text 1</div>
  <div class="item">text 2</div>
  <div class="item">text 3</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="tabs">
  <span class="tab">1</span>
  <span class="tab">2</span>
  <span class="tab">3</span>
</div>
<div class="tabs-items">
  <div class="item">text 1</div>
  <div class="item">text 2</div>
  <div class="item">text 3</div>
</div>
```

Если на странице расположен один блок с табами, то все работает отлично. Но если их несколько, то они начинают работать некорректно, как один.Как сделать чтобы блоки с табами работали независимо друг от друга ? Как сделать код проще и лучше ?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы они работали независимо друг от друга, надо их обернуть в отдельные дивы и работать уже с каждой конкретной обёрткой:

```js
$('.tab-wrap').each(function(){

  let tabTabs = $(this).find('.tab');
  let tabItems = $(this).find('.item');
  
  tabTabs.each(function(i){
    $(this).click(function(){
      $(this).addClass('on');
      tabTabs.not(this).removeClass('on');
      $(tabItems[i]).addClass('on');
      tabItems.not(tabItems[i]).removeClass('on');
    });
  });
  
});
```

```css
.tabs .tab{display:inline-block;padding:5px 10px;margin:0 10px 20px 10px;border:1px solid #333;cursor:pointer}
.tabs .tab.on{background-color:coral}
.tabs-items .item{display:none}
.tabs-items .item.on{display:block}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-wrap">
  <div class="tabs">
    <span class="tab on">1</span>
    <span class="tab">2</span>
    <span class="tab">3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="tabs-items">
    <div class="item on">text 1</div>
    <div class="item">text 2</div>
    <div class="item">text 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="tab-wrap">
  <div class="tabs">
    <span class="tab on">11</span>
    <span class="tab">22</span>
    <span class="tab">33</span>
  </div>
  <div class="tabs-items">
    <div class="item on">text 11</div>
    <div class="item">text 22</div>
    <div class="item">text 33</div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="tab-wrap">
  <div class="tabs">
    <span class="tab on">111</span>
    <span class="tab">222</span>
    <span class="tab">333</span>
  </div>
  <div class="tabs-items">
    <div class="item on">text 111</div>
    <div class="item">text 222</div>
    <div class="item">text 333</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант на чистом JS

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.tabs-wrapper').forEach((e) => {
  let tabTabs = e.querySelectorAll('.tabs .tab');
  let tabItems = e.querySelectorAll('.tabs-items .item');
 for(let i =0;i<tabTabs.length;i++) {
     tabTabs[0].click();
      tabTabs[i].onclick = () => {
        tabTabs.forEach((e)  => { e.classList.remove('on') }); 
        tabItems.forEach((e)  => { e.classList.remove('on') });
        tabTabs[i].classList.add('on');
        tabItems[i].classList.add('on');
     }
   }
 });
```

```css
.tabs .tab{display:inline-block;padding:5px 10px;margin:0 10px 20px 10px;border:1px solid #333;cursor:pointer}

.tabs .tab.on{background-color:coral}
.tabs-items .item{display:none}
.tabs-items .item.on{display:block}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<hr>
<div class="tabs-wrapper">
   <div class="tabs">
    <span class="tab">1</span>
    <span class="tab">2</span>
    <span class="tab">3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="tabs-items">
    <div class="item">text 1</div>
    <div class="item">text 2</div>
    <div class="item">text 3</div>
  </div> 
</div>
<hr>
<div class="tabs-wrapper">
   <div class="tabs">
    <span class="tab">1</span>
    <span class="tab">2</span>
    <span class="tab">3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="tabs-items">
    <div class="item">text 1</div>
    <div class="item">text 2</div>
    <div class="item">text 3</div>
  </div> 
</div>
```